# Crawlspace Vapor Barrier Overkill?

Tags: vapor-barrier, crawlspace

I am about to install a vapor barrier in my damp Atlanta, Georgia area rental home. I plan to seal it about 3 feet up the poured concrete walls and overlap and seal all seams essentially creating an encapsulation of the space.

My question is:

Is this product overkill?

http://www.mytarp.com/20-x-100-husky-yellow-guard-vapor-barrier.aspx

Would something like this (cheaper) work just as well?

http://www.mytarp.com/20-x-100-10-mil-clear-plastic-sheeting.aspx
http://www.mytarp.com/20-x-100-10-mil-black-plastic-sheeting.aspx

They are both 10 mil products, but one is more of a name brand / branded vapor barrier where the other is just 10 mil plastic sheeting.

Comment: Permeability is probably the same between the two products, but the Husky brand says that it's  ASTM E 1745 Class A, B, C rated. [Class A](http://www.stegoindustries.com/faqs/what_is_astm_e_1745.php) has the highest puncture and tearing resistance, so if you're going to walk or crawl over the installed plastic from time to time, it's probably worth paying the extra money for the better product, since it meets the highest certification level, but the cheaper one isn't certified.

Comment: I have clear plastic on the ground in my crawl space in South Carolina. It gets damp under it too. I've done a lot of work under my house on the plastic, but have never noticed any problem with it. But, I would make sure to remove anything that could punch a hole in it while your're laying it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's going on a smooth soft surface the clear stuff is fine.  Over rocks or large gravel, the yellow would be better.